# Using Variables Between 2 JButtons

Tags: java, variables, jbutton

i have 2 `JButtons`

```
  private void startActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
  if (evt.getSource() == start) {
 String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Your name");
     }
   }
```

and

```
private void endActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
  if (evt.getSource() == end) {

       System.out.println(name);

     }
   }
```

But in `end` name is not found 
How can i use the variable `name` in both `JButton`s

Comment: Keep the `name` as an instance field of the class

Comment: @MadProgrammer But i need to keep the original value of `name`

Comment: Could you pass in "name" as a parameter?

Comment: Then create a second instance field, basic solution remains the same